# Push Array every element by 1 index

Tags: php

I have this array `$boxes->vals` starting at index `0`

What I want to do is that I want to PUSH every element by one index.

```
$temp_arr = array();
$tt = 0;
foreach ($boxes->vals as $k => $v) {
    $temp_arr[$k + 1] = $v;

    $tt = $k;
}

$boxes->vals = $temp_arr;

foreach ($boxes->vals as $k => $v) {


    if ($k % 3 == 0) {
        echo '<li></li>';
    }
}
```

But finally after `$boxes->vals = $temp_arr;` 
**PROBLEM** is I get the array with the first element is removed.

**Main Goal** is to write `<li></li>` after every 3rd iteration.

Comment: And what is the problem/question now?

Comment: ` I get the array with the first element is skipped.`

Comment: dont update key index, just update loop code to : if (($k+1) % 3 == 0) {
        echo '<li></li>';
    }

Comment: you want show first and every 3rd iteration why not use $k % 3 == 1?

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
foreach ($temp_arr as $k => $v) {
    if ( ($k +1) % 3 == 1) {
       echo '<li></li>';
    }
}
```